# What are the drawbacks of V-measure clustering evaluation method?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, model-evaluations

What are the drawbacks of V-measure clustering evaluation method?

For evaluating what clustering algorithms, is the V-measure evaluation method suitable?

Answer (score 0):

It is one of many heuristics.

Don't use it for evaluating clustering results. Use it as a guide for which result (or parameter, e.g., k) to explore *first*.

But there is no guarantee that the 'better' result by V measure is *actually* better.

Comment: What are the drawbacks and limitations of this measure?